# Popup alert is firing multiple time in $stateChangeSuccess

Tags: angularjs

I am using 1.x version of angular js. I have written the $stateChangeSuccess with ionicPopup.confirm. Here is my code

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess",function(evt,toState,toParams,fromState,fromParams){
if($rootScope.userinfo!=null && $location.url()=="/login1"){
    $state.go(fromState.name)
    $ionicPopup.confirm({
        title:"confirm",
        content:"Want to Exit App"
    }).then(function(res){
        if(res){
            $rootScope.userinfo=null;
            $state.go(toState.name)
        }
        else{
            $state.go(fromState.name)

        }
    })
   }
})
```

As soon as I tap the back button from mobile, it popup, but fires multiple times, don't know the reason though try to find out.

One more thing i noticed that its calling the condition four times exactly.

Comment: Instead of using $stateChangeSuccess try using $stateChangeStart may help u

Comment: @NitinAgarwal. Its works in browser while testing working great. But in app its even not popup. Any more help will good for me.

Comment: In mobile phone you may not have `$location.url()`. So, try to use `fromState` or `toState` as your requirement

Comment: Add a plunker and tell me what you want to do exactly.

Comment: Let me correct @Mr_Perfect. $location.url() will not been seen but it presence so no matter of using or not this. My problem is that pop is firing based on the conditions but it doing the same activity multiple times

Comment: Can you please add plunker?